# initializing a multidimensional array in a struct in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, initialization

hi i'm working on this program that calculates the various calculations of a matrix (eg determinant and trace and stuff) and i want to use an array in a struct to create a matrix.

in my calculations.h header file, i have this:

```
struct matrices {
     int matrix[3][3]; };
```

in my calculations.c implementation file i have this function that basically creates the matrix after taking integer inputs from the user:

```
struct matrices creation (int x, int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8 ) {
     struct matrices mmm = {{x, x1, x2}, {x3, x4, x5}, {x6, x7, x8}};
     return mmm;
}
```

however, i get the error message `error: extra brace group at end of initializer` directed to the line `struct matrices mmm = {{x, x1, x2}, {x3, x4, x5}, {x6, x7, x8}};`

thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean to use `struct matrices mmm` ?

Comment: What sj95126 said, there is no struct called matrix in your code.

Comment: yes sorry, i was changing my code for some reason and forgot to move that over. the issue isn't the name difference tho @sj95126

Answer (score 0):

> in my calculations.c implementation file i have this function that
> basically creates the matrix after taking integer inputs from the
> user:

In general it is not practical to have a separate `int` for each position of the matrix. What if it were a 30x30 matrix?

Instead you use indexes to get each value from the user into the desired position.

Your function:

```
struct matrices creation (
    int  x, int x1, int x2,
    int x3, int x4, int x5,
    int x6, int x7, int x8 ) {
     struct matrices mmm = {{x, x1, x2}, {x3, x4, x5}, {x6, x7, x8}};
     return mmm;
}
```

just takes 8 `int` to stuff into an array and them return *a copy* of the array, but is the same as

```
  matrix another = { {x1, x2, x3}, {x4, x5, x6}, {x7, x8, x9} };
```

#### example

```
#include<stdio.h>
  
typedef int matrix[3][3];
int show(matrix);

int main(void)
{
  matrix one = {{1,2,3}, { 4,5,6}, { 7,8,9}};
  show(one);
  int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9;
  x1 = x2 = x3 = x4 = x5 = x6 = x7 = x8 = x9 = 42;
  x5 = -4242;
  matrix another = { {x1, x2, x3}, {x4, x5, x6}, {x7, x8, x9} };
  show(another);
  return 0;
}

int show(matrix M)
{
    for ( int y=0;y<3;y+=1)
    {
        for( int x = 0;x<3;x+=1) printf("%6d ", M[y][x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};
```

shows

```
     1      2      3 
     4      5      6 
     7      8      9 

    42     42     42 
    42  -4242     42 
    42     42     42
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is a type. You mean either the structure `struct matrices` or the structure `struct matrix` in the declarations of the code snippet.

If to ignore the typo the initialization will look like

```
struct matrices {
     int matrix[3][3]; };

struct matrices creation (int x, int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8 ) {
     struct matrices mmm = 
     { 
         {
             { x,  x1, x2 }, 
             { x3, x4, x5 }, 
             { x6, x7, x8 }
         } 
      };
     return mmm;
}
```

Or the following way

```
struct matrices {
     int matrix[3][3]; };
     
struct matrices creation(int x, int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6, int x7, int x8 ) {
     struct matrices mmm = 
     {
        .matrix = 
        {
            {x, x1, x2}, {x3, x4, x5}, {x6, x7, x8}
        }           
     };
     
     return mmm;
}
```

That is the aggregate struct matrix contains a two dimensional array.
So you need to use one more pair of braces.